# Appending strings in Oracle within a plsql loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Like any programming language you can use a simple =+ to append to a variable string, but how do you do that within an Oracle PlSql block?

Example

```
my_string string

my_string = 'bla';

while ...(not greater than 10)
my_string += 'i';
```

expected output: bla12345678910

Answer (score 29):

Concatenation operator is `||`
However, there is not short form of the concatenation that you are looking for (i.e. +=).

You can try this:

```
DECLARE
 lvOutPut VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
    lvOutPut := 'BLA';
    FOR i in 1..10 LOOP
        lvOutPut := lvOutPut || i;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lvOutPut);
END;
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Sometimes I just assume =+ is a default within any program language. Was going to use the long hand method of that.